# How to run the v8 Promise tests against my own implementation?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, testing, v8

I have implemented a module that *should* look exactly like a regular ES6 Promise;  and I want to test it as such.

The files that test promises in the node tests are here:
https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/deps/v8/test/mjsunit/es6/promises.js

However I cannot work out how to run these files.  After putting in the requisite require for my own module the files fail with syntax errors of missing functions.  I seem to be missing some kind of testing suite but can't work out which it is.

---

The syntax errors are for missing function: eg. `describe`

I have inserted a line at the top of the file like so:

`var Promise = require('my-promise-module');`

this module should appear no different to:

`module.exports = Promise;`

I am attempting to run the file like `node ./promise.js` (where promise.js is the linked test file).

This is obviously not the right way to run it as many of the functions called in the test file are not available (e.g. %abortJS),  though I cannot work out what the test file needs to run.

Comment: _"have implemented a module that should look exactly like a regular ES6 Promise"_ Can include `js` at Question ?

Comment: You are going to need to `require` your promise code to begin with. But who knows, you may or may not be doing that, you have not shown any code, or disclosed any errors.

Comment: @guest271314 the module should look exactly like `module.exports = Promise;`.  In fact that is how I am testing the testing setup (ie. that should pass).  The require line is added to the top of the file `var Promise = require('my-promise-module');` (or simply `var Promise = Promise`).

The problem is functions such as `describe` which appear to be part of the test script are not defined,  so I am obviously not calling it right!

Comment: `describe` isn't even used in the file that you linked to.

Comment: @Xotic750 my apologies,  that was a different (and less preferable) test script.  I have corrected it for this one:

The error is on not having the "%AbortJS" function,  line 92

Doing a wget then calling `node ./promise.js` should hopefully render the same error.